# Summing the odds over the evens

Tags: calculus

How would you go about showing $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n\frac{1\cdot3 \cdots (2n-1)}{2\cdot 4 \cdots (2n)}$$ is conditionally convergent? Thanks!

Comment: Leibniz criterion.

Comment: $$\sum\limits_{n\geq 0}(-1)^n \frac{(2n-1)!!}{2^n n!}=\sum\limits_{n\geq 0}(-1)^n \frac{(2n-1)!!}{(2n)!!}$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to show (non-absolute) convrgence is to observe that the summand takes the form

$$(-1)^n \frac{(2 n)!}{2^{2 n} (n!)^2} \sim \frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{\pi n}} \quad (n \to \infty)$$

The latter expression may be derived from Stirling's approximation.  Now it should be seen that the series converges by the Leibniz criterion, as the absolute value of the summand clearly decreases.

Comment: Is it possible to avoid Stirlings formula? Are you able to use $/frac{1}{2/sqrt{n}} < |a_n| < /frac{1}{/sqrt{2n-1}}$?

Comment: @pel: I suppose you could find a way to avoid Stirling, but why?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**
$$(-1)^n \frac{(2n-1)!!}{2^n n!} = (-1)^n\frac{(2n)!}{2^{2n} (n!)^2}$$
$$\simeq (-1)^n\frac{(2n/e)^{2n}\sqrt{4\pi n}}{2\pi n 2^{2n} (n/e)^{2n}}=  \frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n \pi}}$$